# Where do I find the topic of a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support

I was searching and I didn't find any help or description of the topic.

Specifically I was searching the differences of Super User and Unix & Linux.

Where is the information of the topics of each Q&A site?

Comment: @RobertLongson Why is it a duplicate?

Comment: Why is it not? It explains what those communities are, and points you to the FAQs for each if you want further explanation.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help Each site has a similar page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Super User you will find it at https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

For Unix & Linux you will find it at https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

For any site just click the Help (?) button near top right of its banner:

[image: Help Center]

and choose **Help Center** then **What topics can I ask about here?**